# A Custom UITabBar inside a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

This is the final result I want (the outline in red is just an illustration of the boarder of the tab bar I want to create and not part of the final result [thank you in advanced!]): [image: custom uitabbar] the UITabBar, including the "hump" around the Planner button, is in front of whatever is being shown in green (the selected view controller in the `UITabBarController`)

#### This is what I have now

I have four classes:

- **`RootTabBarController: UITabBarController`** which contains three view controllers

  - **`AgendaViewController: UIViewController`** just a view controller
  - **`UIViewController`** this creates a placeholder button for the Planner View Controller. When the user clicks this button, the `RootTabBarController` prevents this selection from happening. But, instead presents the `PlanViewController` linked in the storyboard
  - **`OrganizeTableViewController: UITableViewController`** this is embedded in a `UINavigationViewController`

this is how they appear in my storyboard: [image: uitabbarcontroller storyboard] if this layout in the storyboard needs to change achieve what I'm aiming for, please let me know :)

**note** I'm using [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621166-tabbarcontroller#declarations) to prevent the middle button to switch to the view controller in red. and this is what instead happens if the plan button is pressed:

```swift
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        // is the selected view controller the AgendaViewController or OranizerTableViewController?
        if
            viewController is AgendaViewController == true ||
            (viewController is UINavigationController == true && (viewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController! is OrganizeTableViewController == true) {
                return true
        }

        // Present PlanViewController
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "show plan", sender: nil)

        // Prevent selecting the placeholder UIViewController linked in the storyboard
        return false
    }
```

Thus, only the left and right buttons on the `RootTabBarController` are selectable while the middle button presents the `PlanViewController` using a segue as a `Show Detailed`

Comment: Use google to search for `custom UITabBar` ... you'll find lots of examples.